# How to enable AirPlay mirroring on an iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, appletv, airplay

On my iPad mini I cannot seem to enable the mirroring feature. AirPlay in the photos app or any video app works fine:

[image: AirPlay in photos app]

However the AirPlay icon is missing in the taskbar, where it should be according to Apple's documentation:

[image: Airplay icon missing in taskbar]

How can I get back the AirPlay icon? I've already tried rebooting all devices.

Edit: This is what I am looking for (source: [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5209))

[image: AirPlay mirroring dialog]

Comment: which ios version r u use?

Comment: Latest for the mini: 6.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another round of reboots (first: software update for the Apple TV, second: reboot of the iPad mini), it now works:

[image: image showing the AirPlay mirroring dialog]

It seems that some hiccup was responsible, which was very, very sticky. So the [often mentioned hint of rebooting](http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad_Troubleshooting/a/How-To-Fix-Airplay-Icon-Missing.htm) does really work. Just try it often enough... :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Photos app uses the Airplay icon in the "taskbar" at the bottom.  You have the AirPlay icon in the upper right of the Photos app, which is how you AirPlay photos.  I think it only shows up in the taskbar if you're playing music, and possibly for movies too.

Doesn't it work using the Airplay icon in the upper right?

Comment: I want to use the mirroring function (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5209), not the normal AirPlay. Somehow, this feature seems to be not very well known... With an iPhone, I can do the mirroring. And according to Apple, the mini should be able to do it as well.